# Poor rendering of HTML elements during rotation

Tags: javascript, html, rendering

I have a simple game of Sudoko written in html. I have a table of 9 rows by 9 columns with different numbers on them that the player can switch their places. When he is finished he clicks on a button that validates that table cells are legal sudoko board. If the table is a solved sudoko, all the cells should rotate to the right using a SetInterval function.

However, some of the cells do not render as fast as the others. The cells at the lower rows stops at some moments to rotate. How can I fix this problem?

this is my code:

```
<body>

<table id="SudukoTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="One" id="C1" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">1</td>
        <td class="One" id="C2" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">1</td>
        <td class="One" id="C3" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">1</td>
        <td class="One" id="C4" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">1</td>
        <td class="One" id="C5" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">1</td>
        <td class="One" id="C6" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">1</td>
        <td class="One" id="C7" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">1</td>
        <td class="One" id="C8" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">1</td>
        <td class="One" id="C9" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">1</td>       
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="Two" id="C10" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">2</td>
        <td class="Two" id="C11" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">2</td>
        <td class="Two" id="C12" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">2</td>
        <td class="Two" id="C13" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">2</td>
        <td class="Two" id="C14" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">2</td>
        <td class="Two" id="C15" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">2</td>
        <td class="Two" id="C16" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">2</td>
        <td class="Two" id="C17" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">2</td>
        <td class="Two" id="C18" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">2</td>        
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="Three" id="C19" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">3</td>
        <td class="Three" id="C20" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">3</td>
        <td class="Three" id="C21" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">3</td>
        <td class="Three" id="C22" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">3</td>
        <td class="Three" id="C23" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">3</td>
        <td class="Three" id="C24" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">3</td>
        <td class="Three" id="C25" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">3</td>
        <td class="Three" id="C26" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">3</td>
        <td class="Three" id="C27" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">3</td>        
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="Four" id="C28" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">4</td>
        <td class="Four" id="C29" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">4</td>
        <td class="Four" id="C30" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">4</td>
        <td class="Four" id="C31" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">4</td>
        <td class="Four" id="C32" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">4</td>
        <td class="Four" id="C33" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">4</td>
        <td class="Four" id="C34" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">4</td>
        <td class="Four" id="C35" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">4</td>
        <td class="Four" id="C36" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">4</td>            
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="Five" id="C37" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">5</td>
        <td class="Five" id="C38" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">5</td>
        <td class="Five" id="C39" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">5</td>
        <td class="Five" id="C40" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">5</td>
        <td class="Five" id="C41" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">5</td>
        <td class="Five" id="C42" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">5</td>
        <td class="Five" id="C43" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">5</td>
        <td class="Five" id="C44" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">5</td>
        <td class="Five" id="C45" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">5</td>        
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="Six" id="C46" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">6</td>
        <td class="Six" id="C47" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">6</td>
        <td class="Six" id="C48" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">6</td>
        <td class="Six" id="C49" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">6</td>
        <td class="Six" id="C50" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">6</td>
        <td class="Six" id="C51" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">6</td>
        <td class="Six" id="C52" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">6</td>
        <td class="Six" id="C53" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">6</td>
        <td class="Six" id="C54" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">6</td>            
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="Seven" id="C55" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">7</td>
        <td class="Seven" id="C56" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">7</td>
        <td class="Seven" id="C57" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">7</td>
        <td class="Seven" id="C58" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">7</td>
        <td class="Seven" id="C59" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">7</td>
        <td class="Seven" id="C60" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">7</td>
        <td class="Seven" id="C61" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">7</td>
        <td class="Seven" id="C62" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">7</td>
        <td class="Seven" id="C63" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">7</td>         
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="Eight" id="C64" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">8</td>
        <td class="Eight" id="C65" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">8</td>
        <td class="Eight" id="C66" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">8</td>
        <td class="Eight" id="C67" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">8</td>
        <td class="Eight" id="C68" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">8</td>
        <td class="Eight" id="C69" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">8</td>
        <td class="Eight" id="C70" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">8</td>
        <td class="Eight" id="C71" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">8</td>
        <td class="Eight" id="C72" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">8</td>          
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="Nine" id="C73" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">9</td>
        <td class="Nine" id="C74" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">9</td>
        <td class="Nine" id="C75" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">9</td>
        <td class="Nine" id="C76" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">9</td>
        <td class="Nine" id="C77" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">9</td>
        <td class="Nine" id="C78" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">9</td>
        <td class="Nine" id="C79" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">9</td>
        <td class="Nine" id="C80" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">9</td>
        <td class="Nine" id="C81" onclick="SwitchWith(this)">9</td>              
    </tr>

</table>
<button id="CheckBtn" onclick="RoateAll()">Finished</button>
```

this is my javascript file:

```
function RotateAll() {

setInterval(function () {
    angle++;

    for (var i = 1; i < 82; i++) {

        var a = document.getElementById("C" + i);
        a.style.webkitTransform = "rotate("+angle+"deg)"

    }
}, 60);
```

}

This is how my table looks like after a number of rotation of its cells:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of 3d transforms to initiate hardware acceleration!

```
#SudukoTable td {
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
   -o-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);

   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;

   -webkit-perspective: 1000;
   -moz-perspective: 1000;
   -ms-perspective: 1000;
   perspective: 1000;
}
```

Check the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/iancwoodward/sT7UJ/4/

3D transforms are intended for 3D (obviously), but when you initiate them by activating the 3rd axis (i.e. Z-axis or translateZ) it has the side effect of also initiating OpenGl drivers which gives you access to hardware acceleration. In other words you are using the 3D processor
in your computer to render animations rather than the normal software rendering. The other 2 properties are to fix jittery animation in certain browsers because they sometimes try to render both sides of the object even though you only intend on showing one side.

Comment: I added your code to my css file and it did the trick. Can you please explain what you have written, what is 3d transforms? I don't have a cube or a 3d object here, only a simple table. Thanks.

Comment: See [this article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css)

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation, this is a really good trick to keep in mind especially when programming for mobile. (almost all animation is terrible on mobile unless you utilize hardware acceleration)

Comment: By the way, the code you wrote the site jsfiddle works fine on google chrome. Why it doesn't work on IE?

Comment: Ie8 doesn't natively support css3. What most web developers do is either accept that and move on or find what is called a shiv or poly fill which gives older browsers new features. You want to be careful with those however because they can cause slowing as well. Btw, you're using WebKit transform property which I would assume only works for WebKit browsers, ie is not WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried another browser? What device are you testing on? Perhaps it is graphics speed related. Try an increment of `angle+=5` and see if this helps.

FYI, there are some typos but I will presume you are testing without the typos. For example:

```
<button id="CheckBtn" onclick="RoateAll()">Finished</button>
```

is missing `t` in `RotateAll()`

```
function RotateAll() {
```

is missing a closing `}`

You should set `angle = 0;` (it is not defined in your code)

Note that with Firefox, you can use:

```
    a.style.MozTransform = "rotate("+angle+"deg)";
```